# Парсинг на PHP. Как заменить строку?

Tags: php

При парсинге выводим какую то информацию

```
echo .$item->description.'<br><br>';
```

Но в этой инфе надо добавить рефссылку. Для этого можно воспользоваться функцией **str_replace()** а для этого все что выводится надо поместить в переменную и там через функцию произвести замену строк.
Но такая комбинация не работает.

```
    $refer = echo .$item->description.'<br><br>'; 
    $refer = str_replace('<A href="http://instaforex.com/ru">instaforex.com</A>',
            '<A href="http://instaforex.com/ru" target="_blank">instaforex.com</A>', $refer); 
echo $refer;
```

В чем ошибка?
Спасибо.

Comment: Это что за онархея?)

    $refer = echo . $item->description

Comment: сам не знаю, как только уже не изголялся. 
Подскажите как данные из 

 .$item->description. 

поместить в переменную.

Comment: $item->description и есть переменная.

Можно скопировать, если это принципиально:

    $myvar = $item->description;

И на будущее - пользуйтесь гуглом. Запросы "php echo", "php str_replace" и "php строки" наверняка расскажут вам много нового и интересного)

Comment: С гугла то и написал. Пробовал разные варианты. Прочитал про функции. Вот Вы написали 

$item->description;

без точек, а в инете в начале и конце точки стоят.

Я еще не проверил Ваш вариант - может он и будет работать.

Comment: Он работает - спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$refer = str_replace(
  '<A href="http://instaforex.com/ru">instaforex.com</A>',
  '<A href="http://instaforex.com/ru" target="_blank">instaforex.com</A>',
  $item->description.'<br><br>'); 
echo $refer;
```

И отвыкайте от 1995-стайл)) Я про теги большими буквами(`<A ...`) и незакрытый `<br>` (`<br />`);

Comment: Спасибо. Только $refer пустой. Надо присвоить значение

   echo $item->description.'<br><br>'; //выводим на печать текст статьи 

Большие теги А я написал потому, что что при анализе они так и ыли написаны. Я всегда пишу маленькие теги. Насчет незакрытый br - сори.

Comment: $refer не пустой (проверили бы что ли сначала). $refer будет равен $item->description.'<br><br>' c замененным куском.

Comment: Только что еще раз проверил. С точной перед $item и без нее.

Если просто написать

echo .$item->description.  - работает, но мне надо поменять код.

Comment: Не может такого быть. Если в $item->description что-то есть, мой код отработает нормально, проверьте, там ли вы его включаете и не заменили ли вы что-то. 

И точку после echo вам кто подсказал? Это бред) echo - команда вывода, точка соединяет строки.

Comment: Написал Ваш код без <br /> - не работало, а с br работает.
Не знаю почему. Спасибо.

Comment: Инет

    foreach ($rss->channel->item as $item) {
    echo '<h5>'.$item->title.'</h5>'; //выводим заголовок статьи 
    echo '<h6>'.$item->pubDate.'</h6>'; 

Но как Вы написали про точки - сразу дошло где ошибка.
Спасибо еще раз.